# Как ускорить выполнение Выполнение GM

Tags: php

Есть класс который служит для приведения фотографий к определенному стандарту 1024 х 756. ДЛя этого я использую GM.

Вопрос так ли я вызываю GM и как можно ускорить выполнение скрипта?

```
class CoreImgFiles {

private $files=[];
public $AllWaySavefiles=[];

public function __construct($allfiles)
{
   self::rewriteArray($allfiles);
   self::saveEvent();
}

private function rewriteArray($allfiles){

    $files = [];
    $file_count = count($allfiles['name'])-1;

    for($i=$file_count;$i>=0;$i--)
    {
        $files[] = $allfiles['tmp_name'][$i];
        unset($allfiles['name'][$i]);
        unset($allfiles['type'][$i]);
        unset($allfiles['tmp_name'][$i]);
        unset($allfiles['error'][$i]);
        unset($allfiles['size'][$i]);
    }
    unset($allfiles);
    return $this->files=$files;
}

private function minimilize($savefile){

    $image=new Gmagick($savefile);

    $width=$image->getimagewidth();
    $height=$image->getimageheight();

    $standartWidth='';
    $standartHeight='';
    $x='';
    $y='';

    if($width>$height) {

        $standartWidth=1024;
        $standartHeight=756;

        $masWidth=1300;
        $masHeight=900;


        $kw=$width/$masWidth;

        $wx=$width/$kw;

        $image->setCompressionQuality(80);
        $image->profileimage('*',null);
        $image->resizeimage($wx, $wx, null, 1, true);


        $x = (($masWidth - $standartWidth) / 2);
        $y = (($masHeight - $standartHeight) / 2);
    }

    if($width<$height) {

        $standartWidth=1024;
        $standartHeight=756;

        $koef=$width/1024;
        $wx=$height/$koef;

        $image->setCompressionQuality(80);
        $image->profileimage('*',null);
        $image->resizeimage($wx, $wx, null, 1, true);

        $x = 0;
        $y = $wx/7.75;

    }

    $image->cropimage($standartWidth, $standartHeight, $x,$y);
    $image->writeimage($savefile);
    $image->destroy();
}

private function saveEvent(){

    $event=mb_substr(sha1(date('YmdHis')), 0,10);

    $Head="img/"."$event";

    mkdir($Head,0777,true);
    chmod($Head, 0777);

    $AllWaySavefiles=[];

    $LengthDaunloadFiles=count($this->files)-1;

    for ($i=$LengthDaunloadFiles;$i>=0;$i--)
    {
        $newname = mb_substr(sha1(date('YmdHis',time()).mt_rand().$this->files[$i]),0,7).'.jpeg';

        $savefile=$Head.'/'."$newname";
        move_uploaded_file($this->files[$i],$savefile);
        unset($this->files[$i]);
        chmod($savefile, 0777);
        self::minimilize($savefile);
        $AllWaySavefiles[]=$savefile;
    }

    return  $this->AllWaySavefiles=$AllWaySavefiles;
}
```

}

Comment: использовать последний пхп, включить opcache, поставить быстрый диск. замерить время выполнения операций и понять что из приведенного является наиболее долгой операцией.

Comment: Самой долгой операцией является вызов функции new Gmagick и последующие манипуляции с фоткой. может ее как то можно по другому вызывать Статически я не пойму как это сделать? и поможет ли это?

Comment: А долго - это сколько ? время засекали ?

Comment: долго это 93 минуты на 1010 фоток. изначальным размером около 3 мб. или 11 фоток в минуту

Comment: зачем вы вообще это делаете на пхп в таких объемах?

Comment: @teran c  целью потестить и дать прикурить апачу. ну а вообще пример есть   opcache и как єта функия работает и что деает?

Comment: @dpi ужас просто (я про скорость), попробуйте переписать обрезалку на голом php, используя `getimagesize`, `imagecreatefromjpeg` и прочие, а потом сравните производительность.